# Location of conf files for PostgreSQL 11 on Ubuntu 16?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

Where are the configuration files located for PostgreSQL 11 on Ubuntu, specifically 16.04?

Postgres Ubuntu packages normally store their configs in `/etc/postgresql/<version>/main`. However, I just purged all postgresql packages, and then install Postgresql 11 vai `sudo apt install postgresql-11`.

Now, the folder `/etc/postgresql` exists, but it's completely empty. Normally the default package install populates the subdirectories with defaults, but there's nothing there. I tried manually populating them and then restarting the server, but I can't connect even thought `sudo service postgresql status` says the server's running?

Did the location of the config files change in PG11? I can't find any mention of this in the release docs. Where are the new config files located on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Even though I ran `sudo apt-get purge postgresql*`, this apparently left the `/var/lib/postgresql/*` directories for previous versions unchanged, and it seems something in there was preventing the new install from initializing the files for version 11.

I fixed this by again purging everything but then also manually deleting `/var/lib/postgresql`. I then re-installed the `postgresql-11` package and everything worked fine.